# Converting UTM to Lat Long inside a Game Engine(Untiy 3d)

Tags: field-calculator, convert, latitude-longitude, utm

This is my first post on Stack Exchange.

I have exhausted my research through the game engine forums, so I am trying this forum since you guys seem to be the experts.

I have an external device that is feeding in UTM grid coordinates into the computer and using Unity 3d Game Engine: www.unity3d.com. This is a VR type project.

Im using C# and Javascript, those are the two accepted languages in Unity. I have found this code for C# online and have tried working it to my project but there seems to be some conversion into the engine errors that im struggling with. Here is the code I found, is this something I can use or will it not work in this context?

Basically I want to plug in my UTM coordinates and spit out Lat/ Long.

Hopefully it is that simple to setup and I have provided enough information about my project.

```
 public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {
     public double utmEast; //The updated UTM Easting
     public double utmNorth; //The updated UTM Northing
     public string utmZone; // The updated UTM Zone user is currently in. 

     public static void ToLatLon(double utmX, double utmY, string utmZone, out double latitude, out double longitude)
     {
     bool isNorthHemisphere = utmZone.Last() >= 'N';

         var diflat = -0.00066286966871111111111111111111111111;
         var diflon = -0.0003868060578;

         var zone = int.Parse(utmZone.Remove(utmZone.Length - 1));
         var c_sa = 6378137.000000;
         var c_sb = 6356752.314245;
         var e2 = Math.Pow((Math.Pow(c_sa, 2) - Math.Pow(c_sb, 2)), 0.5) / c_sb;
         var e2cuadrada = Math.Pow(e2, 2);
         var c = Math.Pow(c_sa, 2) / c_sb;
         var x = utmX - 500000;
         var y = isNorthHemisphere ? utmY : utmY - 10000000;   
         var s = ((zone * 6.0) - 183.0);
         var lat = y / (c_sa * 0.9996);
         var v = (c / Math.Pow(1 + (e2cuadrada * Math.Pow(Math.Cos(lat), 2)), 0.5)) * 0.9996;
         var a = x / v;
         var a1 = Math.Sin(2 * lat);
         var a2 = a1 * Math.Pow((Math.Cos(lat)), 2);
         var j2 = lat + (a1 / 2.0);
         var j4 = ((3 * j2) + a2) / 4.0;
         var j6 = ((5 * j4) + Math.Pow(a2 * (Math.Cos(lat)), 2)) / 3.0;
         var alfa = (3.0 / 4.0) * e2cuadrada;
         var beta = (5.0 / 3.0) * Math.Pow(alfa, 2);
         var gama = (35.0 / 27.0) * Math.Pow(alfa, 3);
         var bm = 0.9996 * c * (lat - alfa * j2 + beta * j4 - gama * j6);
         var b = (y - bm) / v;
         var epsi = ((e2cuadrada * Math.Pow(a, 2)) / 2.0) * Math.Pow((Math.Cos(lat)), 2);
         var eps = a * (1 - (epsi / 3.0));
         var nab = (b * (1 - epsi)) + lat;
         var senoheps = (Math.Exp(eps) - Math.Exp(-eps)) / 2.0;
         var delt = Math.Atan(senoheps / (Math.Cos(nab)));
         var tao = Math.Atan(Math.Cos(delt) * Math.Tan(nab));

         longitude = ((delt * (180.0 / Math.PI)) + s) + diflon;
         latitude = ((lat + (1 + e2cuadrada * Math.Pow(Math.Cos(lat), 2) - (3.0 / 2.0) * e2cuadrada * Math.Sin(lat) * Math.Cos(lat) * (tao - lat)) * (tao - lat)) * (180.0 / Math.PI)) + diflat;

         print(latitude);// Looking to display in the Console Log Lat.
         print(longitude);// Looking to display in the Console Log Long.
     }
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried using this code? Have you compared it to deprojection code in s GIS package? What exact errors did you encounter?  I doubt there's anything we can do to help without any GIS content. If you strip your code of gaming references and provide inputs and outputs we might be able to help, but you could do more to help yourself.

Comment: I do not have any GIS software, is this necessary to have a library of content in my project or is it possible to do the conversion without it and keep updating the new Lat/Lon in real time?

Comment: Look into FME 2016 they are soon to be supporting Unity see https://trello.com/c/ZimNaaK4/56-unity try http://www.safe.com/support/support-resources/fme-downloads/beta/ and request a 30 day trial

Comment: If you decide to go with this code, there are some optimizations you can make like pulling out and/or hard-coding all constant values like e2, c, possibly s, etc.

Comment: Did you problem solved? I am looking for the same!